# R dplyr rowwise mean or min and other methods?

Tags: r, row, dplyr

How can I get with dplyr the minimum (or mean) value of each row on a data.frame?
I mean the same result as

```
apply(mydataframe, 1, mean) 
apply(mydataframe, 1, min)
```

I've tried

```
mydataframe %>% rowwise() %>% mean
```

or

```
mydataframe %>% rowwise() %>% summarise(mean)
```

or other combinations but I always get errors, I don't know the proper way.

I know that I could also use rowMeans, but there is no simple "rowMin" equivalent.
There also exist a matrixStats package but most functions don't accept data.frames, only matrixes.

If I want to calculate the min rowwise I could use
do.call(pmin, mydataframe)
Is there anything simple like this for the rowwise mean?

```
do.call(mean, mydataframe)
```

doesn't work, I guess I need a pmean function or something more complex.

Thanks

In order to compare the results we could all work on the same example:

```
set.seed(124)
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10))
```

Comment: Use `mutate` instead of `summarise`, by the way `do.call(pmin, mydataframe)` *is* a row wise `mean`- try, `do.call(pmin, mtcars[c("gear", "carb")])` for example, so not sure what's your issue with it

Comment: Could you write the full sentence, please? And how do you include options for "mean", for example na.rm=TRUE

Comment: For example, (for the `mtcars` datra): `mtcars %>% rowwise() %>% do(data.frame(., res = mean(unlist(.), na.rm = TRUE)))`

Comment: The time cost of `as.matrix` to use `matrixStats` would be pretty low. Also, something like `mtcars[cbind(1:nrow(mtcars),max.col(-mtcars))]` works to find a minimum in each row.

Comment: @skan you could also simply use `rowMeans` like this `mtcars$mymean = rowMeans(mtcars)`

Comment: @DavidArenburg What's the meaning of the dot?

Comment: @thelatemail Why the minus inside  "max.col(-mtcars)" ?

Comment: @skan a max of a negative is a min

Comment: yes, but why not calculate the min.col?  It could also be related with selection of columns or something else.

Answer (score 18):

I suppose this is what you were trying to accomplish:

```
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10))

library(dplyr)
df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Min = min(A, B, C), Mean = mean(c(A, B, C)))

#             A          B           C        Min        Mean
# 1   1.3720142  0.2156418  0.61260582  0.2156418  0.73342060
# 2  -1.4265665 -0.2090585 -0.05978302 -1.4265665 -0.56513600
# 3   0.6801410  1.5695065 -2.70446924 -2.7044692 -0.15160724
# 4   0.0335067  0.8367425 -0.83621791 -0.8362179  0.01134377
# 5  -0.2068252 -0.2305140  0.23764322 -0.2305140 -0.06656532
# 6  -0.3571095 -0.8776854 -0.80199141 -0.8776854 -0.67892877
# 7   1.0667424 -0.6376245 -0.41189564 -0.6376245  0.00574078
# 8  -1.0003376 -1.5985281  0.90406055 -1.5985281 -0.56493504
# 9  -0.8218494  1.1100531 -1.12477401 -1.1247740 -0.27885677
# 10  0.7868666  0.6099156 -0.58994138 -0.5899414  0.26894694
```

Comment: How do you avoid to specify every column name?. Sometimes you have too many.

Comment: @skan I thought that `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_(Mean = min(names(df)))` should work, but it doesn't, only the first column is considered. And for `mean` it gives out an error. No idea why,

Comment: if anybody can fix it that would be the nicer solution

Comment: @Molx3 I've seen that the problem is like "df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_(Min = min(c("A", "B", "C")))"  vs 
"df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(Min = min(c(A, B, C)))"   The second one works, I guess we need that  the names function return Non-String values.

Comment: @skan If you need to use the names quoted, you have to use the dplyr functions ending with `_`, like `mutate_`, `summarise_ `, etc.

Comment: `mutate` expects an `expression(c(A,B,C,...))` so one way to avoid specifying every column name is by using `eval(parse())` like this: `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate(argmin = which.min(eval(parse(text = sprintf("c(%s)", paste(names(.), collapse = ","))))))` .

The suggestion to use `mutate_` does not work for `which.min`. Example: `df %>% rowwise() %>% mutate_(argmin = which.min(c("A","B","C")))`.

Answer (score 9):

There seems to be talk that some `dplyr` functions like `rowwise` could be deprecated in the long term (such rumblings on display [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/should-i-move-away-from-do-and-rowwise/2857/2)). Instead, certain functions from the `map` family of functions -- such as the [`pmap`](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html) function -- from `purrr` can be used to perform this sort of calculation:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% mutate(Min = pmap(df, min), Mean = rowMeans(.))

#              A          B           C        Min       Mean
# 1  -1.38507062  0.3183367 -1.10363778  -1.385071 -0.7234572
# 2   0.03832318 -1.4237989  0.44418506  -1.423799 -0.3137635
# 3  -0.76303016 -0.4050909 -0.20495061 -0.7630302 -0.4576905
# 4   0.21230614  0.9953866  1.67563243  0.2123061  0.9611084
# 5   1.42553797  0.9588178 -0.13132225 -0.1313222  0.7510112
# 6   0.74447982  0.9180879 -0.19988298  -0.199883  0.4875616
# 7   0.70022940 -0.1509696  0.05491242 -0.1509696  0.2013907
# 8  -0.22935461 -1.2230688 -0.68216549  -1.223069 -0.7115296
# 9   0.19709386 -0.8688243 -0.72770415 -0.8688243 -0.4664782
# 10  1.20715377 -1.0424854 -0.86190429  -1.042485 -0.2324120
```

Mean is a special case (hence the use of the base function `rowMeans`), since `mean` on data.frame objects was deprecated with R 3.0.

Comment: For mean in pmap, can also use `pmap_dbl(., ~mean(c(...)))` per https://stackoverflow.com/a/50240617/3217870

Answer (score 6):

With `dplyr` 1.0.0 you could use `rowwise` with `c_across` :

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Min = min(c_across(A:C)), 
          Mean = mean(c_across(A:C)))

#       A      B       C    Min   Mean
#     <dbl>  <dbl>   <dbl>  <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1 -1.39    0.318 -1.10   -1.39  -0.723
# 2  0.0383 -1.42   0.444  -1.42  -0.314
# 3 -0.763  -0.405 -0.205  -0.763 -0.458
# 4  0.212   0.995  1.68    0.212  0.961
# 5  1.43    0.959 -0.131  -0.131  0.751
# 6  0.744   0.918 -0.200  -0.200  0.488
# 7  0.700  -0.151  0.0549 -0.151  0.201
# 8 -0.229  -1.22  -0.682  -1.22  -0.712
# 9  0.197  -0.869 -0.728  -0.869 -0.466
#10  1.21   -1.04  -0.862  -1.04  -0.232
```

Answer (score 5):

How about this?

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(t(mtcars)) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean))
```

For extra clarity, you could add another `t()` at the end:

```
as.data.frame(t(mtcars)) %>%
  summarise_all(funs(mean)) %>%
  t()
```

Comment: Could you get something as easy but introducing the resulting column on the original data.frame?

Comment: This calculates the mean for each _column_, not _row_! So it doesn't answer the original question. And btw, `summarise_each` is meanwhile deprecated in favor of the more specific `summarise_all` and `summarise_at`.

Comment: @SalimB are you sure? I have a transpose `t()` in there that ensures we are summarizing rows not columns. I will update to the non-deprecated version of `summarise_x`

Comment: @JasonAizkalns Ah, now I see! Sorry, my bad, didn't notice the `t()`. Your answer is correct, of course. The additional `t()` at the end you've added improves clarity a lot :)

Answer (score 4):

One `dplyr` and `purrr` option where the select helpers could be used:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Min = select(., everything()) %>% reduce(pmin),
        Max = select(., everything()) %>% reduce(pmax))

             A          B           C        Min        Max
1  -1.38507062  0.3183367 -1.10363778 -1.3850706  0.3183367
2   0.03832318 -1.4237989  0.44418506 -1.4237989  0.4441851
3  -0.76303016 -0.4050909 -0.20495061 -0.7630302 -0.2049506
4   0.21230614  0.9953866  1.67563243  0.2123061  1.6756324
5   1.42553797  0.9588178 -0.13132225 -0.1313222  1.4255380
6   0.74447982  0.9180879 -0.19988298 -0.1998830  0.9180879
7   0.70022940 -0.1509696  0.05491242 -0.1509696  0.7002294
8  -0.22935461 -1.2230688 -0.68216549 -1.2230688 -0.2293546
9   0.19709386 -0.8688243 -0.72770415 -0.8688243  0.1970939
10  1.20715377 -1.0424854 -0.86190429 -1.0424854  1.2071538
```

Or since `dplyr 1.0.0`:

```
df %>%
 mutate(Min = reduce(across(everything()), pmin),
        Max = reduce(across(everything()), pmax))
```

Comment: This was nice because I could use `ends_with` to calculate the min among only a few columns. `df %>% mutate(mindate = select(., ends_with("date")) %>% reduce(pmin, na.rm=T))`

Answer (score 0):

Think found a solution - just transpose your data.frame:

```
x <- data_frame(x = rnorm(10), 
            y = rnorm(10))

# A tibble: 10 × 2
        x             y
    <dbl>         <dbl>
1  -1.1240392  0.9306028477
2  -0.8213379  0.2500495105
3  -0.8289104 -0.3693704483
4  -0.6486601 -1.1421141986
5   0.5098542 -0.3703368343
6  -0.3644690 -0.0003744377
7   0.7404057  0.1166905738
8  -0.2475214 -0.0802864865
9   0.2637841 -0.7717699521
10  1.4092874  0.2998021578

x %>% 
  t() %>% 
  data.frame() %>% 
  mutate_all(funs(min)) %>% 
  unique() %>% 
  t()

         1
X1  -1.1240392
X2  -0.8213379
X3  -0.8289104
X4  -1.1421142
X5  -0.3703368
X6  -0.3644690
X7   0.1166906
X8  -0.2475214
X9  -0.7717700
X10  0.2998022
```

Comment: If your dataframe is big transposing twice needs a long time and a lot of memory.

Comment: Agree. I think it depends on expectations - I am using this approach on data.frames with several thousand rows and tens of columns and it works sufficiently fast.

Answer (score 0):

How do you avoid having to specify every column name? Like this:

```
set.seed(124)
df <- data.frame(A=rnorm(10), B=rnorm(10), C=rnorm(10))

library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(Mean = mean(
    eval(
      # The snippet can also be wrapped within a function
      parse(text = sprintf("c(%s)", paste(names(.), collapse = ",")))
    )
  ),
  ArgMin = which.min(
    eval(
      parse(text = sprintf("c(%s)", paste(names(.), collapse = ",")))
    )
  ))
```

or

```
getColnamesExpr <- function(df_names) parse(text = sprintf("c(%s)", paste(df_names, collapse = ",")))

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    Mean = mean(eval(getColnamesExpr(names(.)))),
    argmin = which.min(eval(getColnamesExpr(names(.))))
  )
```