# Iterate over data frame columns to calculate the mean

Tags: r, loops, dataframe, iteration

I want to iterate over two columns of a data frame, calculate the mean if values in both columns exist and if not just use the value that exists in either columns. Here is a dummy example of a much bigger datasets!

```
  dummy <- data.frame(
  name = c("A", "B", "C" , "D"),
  x = c(66, 80, NA, 23),
  y = c(56, 90, 50, NA))
```

I want the output to look like this:

```
     name  x  y Mean
1    A 66 56 61
2    B 80 90 85
3    C NA 50 50
4    D 23 NA 23
```

Comment: rowMeans(dummy[,sapply(dummy, is.numeric)], na.rm = TRUE)

Comment: `rowMeans(dummy[-1], na.rm = TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

I would use the dplyr package to do this. Please also tell us what you tried!

Also a duplicate question can be found here: [R dplyr rowwise mean or min and other methods?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31598935/r-dplyr-rowwise-mean-or-min-and-other-methods)

```
dummy_2 <- dummy %>% 
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(Mean = mean(c(x,y),na.rm=TRUE))
```